# foreach loop results to INSERT into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, insert

I have three different div's that contain the checkout information.

1. Shipping info
2. Billing Info
3. Order confirmation

The shipping information and billing information is obtained by the customer entering that information in manually, but the order confirmation, that contains what they are ordering, the quantity, and pertinent information to that order resides there. That information is obtained from a foreach loop I have in place that displays the information based on the product's ID.

I am trying to figure out how I am going to `INSERT` the string that displays from my `foreach` loop into my database. I have an order report page that I want to display what was ordered.

For the shipping information, I validate it and then send my query in with that information. Like this...

```
<?php
if(Input::exists()) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'fullname' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        )

if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $fullname = trim( $_POST['customer_name'] );
  ?>

<div class="field">
     <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
     <div class="center"><input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" name="fullname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('firstname')); ?>" required></div>
</div>
```

The part that I am really confused with is how to INSERT the actual string this `foreach` loop displays. If the result of my `foreach` loop was:

2 balls

4 shoes.

I want that information to send in with my query.

This is how I have the Order confirmation section as of now..

```
<div class="checkoutconfirmationcontainer">
<?php foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
      $product_id = $product['product_id'];
?>
      <span class="tealmedium"><?php echo $product['quantity'] . " - "  . $products[$product_id]['name'] . $message; ?></span><br><br><br>
           <div class="floatleft"><div class="smallerimgcontainer">
           <?php
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");
           if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;
                if($row['image'] == ""){
                     echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/coming_soon.png' alt='Coming Soon'>";
                } else {
                     echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/".$row['img']."' alt='Product Picture'>";
                }
                echo "<br><br><br><br>";
           }
           ?>
           </div></div>
           <div class="checkoutitemsummary">
           <?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'];?><?php echo $products[$product_id]['name']; ?> </a>
                <p><span class="redprice"><?php echo '$' . $products[$product_id]['price'] . "<br />"; }?></span></p>
           </div>
```

How can I get the results of my `foreach` loop to be inserted into my database with my query?

Shopping Cart

```
<tr>
                                <th class="cartth">Name</th>
                                <th class="cartth">Price</th>
                                <th class="cartth">Category</th>
                                <th class="cartth">Quantity</th>
                            </tr>
<?php                               
                        $base_price = 0;
                        foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                                    $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                                    $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                                    $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];
?>
                                <tr>
                                        <td class="carttd"><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'];?><?php echo $products[$product_id]['name']; ?> </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="carttd"><?php echo '$' . $products[$product_id]['price']; ?></td> 
                                        <td class="carttd"><?php echo $products[$product_id]['category']; ?></td>
                                        <td class="carttd">
                                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='quantity[$product_id]'  value='" . $product['quantity'] . "' />"; ?> </td>                                         
                                </tr>
<?php
                                }
```

Javascript/Jquery that produces my div transition:

```
$('.checkoutmenu>li').on('click',function(e){
    $('.checkoutprocess>.'+ e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});


<script>                    
$('.paymentinfocontainer').hide();
$('.confirmationinfocontainer').hide();
</script>
<script>
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $(".checkoutprocess > div").hide();
    $('.paymentinfocontainer').show("slow");
});
</script>
<script>
$('#button3 ').click(function () {
    $(".checkoutprocess > div").hide();
    $('.confirmationinfocontainer').show("slow");
});
</script>

<script>
/*
$('#button1').click(function () {
    $(".checkoutprocess > div").hide();
    $('.shippinginfocontainer').show("slow");
});
</script>
<script>
$('#button2 ').click(function () {
    $(".checkoutprocess > div").hide();
    $('.paymentinfocontainer').show("slow");
});
</script>
<script>
$('#button3 ').click(function () {
    $(".checkoutprocess > div").hide();
    $('.confirmationinfocontainer').show("slow");
});
*/
</script>
```

Comment: that does make any sense. you're fetching/displaying ALL of your products? on an order confirmation page? That'd be like amazon spitting out 600 kajillion items they carry and burying the ONE item you ordered on page 235234526345234523423 of your invoice.

Comment: no, only the products added to the cart will display in the order confirmation section. I just can't figure out how to send the string of it to my database.

Comment: Your first code example, it does not break from PHP back to HTML. There is a lot that does not make sense here. When you do you see when you do `print_r($_SESSION)` ?

Comment: That's because I just posted what was relevant. The input fields are in html farther down the page. I will edit my question to reflect that. I do not use the print function in this.  I'm just wonder how I can get the results (string this produces)... <?php echo '$' . $products[$product_id]['price']  to be sent to my database in the string form.

Comment: @MarcB  Actually, I found my product on page 1,202,320,748 after having my bot click "Next >" 1,202,320,747 times!

Comment: If you are looking to submit info contained in a <div> with unique id, not an <input>, an ajax form submittal is probably going to be a more straight forward approach.

Comment: I am using an action to a different page once this has been submitted. The information I'm trying to figure out how to send in the query is not an input field. It is echod out data from my database.

Comment: Use JQuery to collect the data from it's element: `var newData = $("#someId").html();` and add that to the data when you post via AJAX.

Comment: @Twisty Is there anyway to do this without AJAX? I do not know AJAX as of yet.

Comment: Yes, you could have the PHP display the content to your page and enter it inot the Value of a hidden field. So the data echoed out needs to be passed along when the form is submitted right?

Comment: @Twisty Yes, I am displaying what I want passed along in the query. I want to do both. Echo it and then send it. Yes the data needs to be passed along when the form is submitted. That is how I will be able to tell what product was ordered.

Comment: Isn't that what the `$_SESSION` variable is already doing? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Twisty I'm not sure how to send the echoed data in a query. All I have ever sent in a query is information typed in an input

Comment: Please edit your post and include an example of the HTML that would be seen when viewing the Shopping Cart. It'll be easier to explain using that as an example.

Comment: I do not see an example of the resulting HTML.What would the order confirmation page that you're asking about look like in HTML?

Comment: @Twisty The order confirmation code that I posted is how it is coded. I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. If this would help you can visit the site I'm creating to see what I mean. It is buyfarbest.com . If you add a product and proceed to checkout, you will see the way I have it structured. I have removed the validation so you can skip through the process.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when I clicked on "3. Order Confirmation", I got the following HTML:

```
<div class="confirmationinfocontainer" style="display: block;">
    <span class="summarytitle"><p>Order Confirmation</p></span>
    <br>
    <div class="floatrightinline">
        <div class="confirmshippinginfo">
            <p>Shipping to:</p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkoutconfirmationcontainer">
        <div name="product_id"></div>
        <span class="tealmedium">1 - Lakers Hat</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="floatleft">
            <div class="smallerimgcontainer">
                <img alt="Coming Soon" src="/productpics/coming_soon.png" class="sizedimg">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkoutitemsummary">
            <a href="./viewProduct.php?view_product=11">Lakers Hat </a>
            <p><span class="redprice">$25<br></span></p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="405bb6b2b562b4f00dac620d3f68620f" name="token">
        <input type="submit" value="Place Your Order" class="widebutton">
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I see you're already making use of a hidden field. So when a users clicks the "Place Your Order" button, you want the details to be passed along. You can simply add these details back to the form via a hidden field. Like so:

```
<div class="checkoutconfirmationcontainer">
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
     $product_id = $product['product_id'];
?>
     <input type="hidden" name="product_quantity[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" />
     <span class="tealmedium"><?php echo $product['quantity'] . " - "  . $products[$product_id]['name'] . $message; ?></span><br><br><br>
     <div class="floatleft"><div class="smallerimgcontainer">
     <?php
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");
     if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;
          if($row['image'] == ""){
               echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/coming_soon.png' alt='Coming Soon'>";
          } else {
               echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/".$row['img']."' alt='Product Picture'>";
          }
          echo "<br><br><br><br>";
     }
     ?>
     </div></div>
     <div class="checkoutitemsummary">
     <?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>{$product['name']} {$products[$product_id]['name']}</a>"; ?>
          <p><span class="redprice"><?php echo '${$products[$product_id]['price']}<br />"; }?></span></p>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" name="token" value="405bb6b2b562b4f00dac620d3f68620f">
     <input class="widebutton" type="submit" value="Place Your Order">
     <br />
</div>
```

Looking over this, I see no `<form>` for this. So I suspect JQuery is handling this somewhere else. So my fix may not really get read if your JQuery or app does not now what to look for, or does not hook onto that hidden field. If this is a framework that you're using or Catalog that you're modifying, check their support. I would say you have a lot more work ahead of you.

Comment: You're correct, I have yet to add a form to this, as I did not want anything to be submitted as I tested the base system of it. I have added my Jquery/JS that hides the divs and slides them in. Why do you say I have a lot more work ahead of me? Other than submitting this and adding a payment gateway, what else would I need to do? Just wondering. This checkout system was entirely created by me. I do have a framework, but it doesn't apply to this.

Comment: I see lots of places you can optimize your code and scripts. I would also keep data of this nature in the `$_SESSION` with minimal interaction from forms. Forms can be abused. This way they can't modify details about the order if they get smart ideas.